# Compute $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac{b_{n-1}}{n 2^n}$ where $b_n=\sum\limits_{k=0}^n\frac{2^k}{k+1}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

Define the sequence $a_n := \frac{2^n}{n+1}$. Then, define the sequence $b_n$, the partial sums of $a_n$; i.e.:
$$b_n=\sum_{k=0}^{n} {a_k}$$
The problem is to compute:
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} {\left(\frac{b_{n-1}}{n 2^n}\right)}$$

This is very difficult to estimate using a computer algebra system. On Maple, I cannot complete an estimate of $100000$ terms under a minute. (However, the sum of the first $1000$ terms is approximately $1.23270055$.)

I am wondering whether the double sum can be converted into a series convolution of some sort; the possibility of getting a $2^{n-m}$ term seems to help that prospect.

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe this is a first step: $$ \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{x^k}{k+1} = \frac 1 x \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{x^{k+1}}{k+1} = \frac 1 x \sum_{k=0}^n \int x^k \, dx = \frac 1 x \int \sum_{k=0}^n x^k \, dx = \frac 1 x \int \frac{1-x^{n+1}}{1-x} \, dx $$

Comment: Please  choose informative titles, see my edit to understand this is often possible.

Comment: @MichaelHardy Did you mean definite integral $\dfrac{1}{x}\int\limits_0^x \dfrac{1-t^{n+1}}{1-t}dt$ ?

Comment: @Ramil : The value of $\displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{x^k}{k+1}$ when $x=0$ is $1/(k+1),$ so you could choose bounds of integration or a "constant of integration" accordingly.

Comment: @MichaelHardy Do you assume that $0^0 = 1$?

Comment: @Ramil : Yes. It is an empty product; therefore it is $1$. Consider the well known series $$ \begin{align} e^z & = 1 + z + \frac{z^2} 2 + \frac{z^3} 6 + \frac{z^4}{24} + \frac{x^5}{120} + \cdots \\  \\ & = \frac{z^0}{0!} + \frac{z^1}{1!} + \frac{z^2}{2!} + \frac{z^3}{3!} + \frac{z^4}{4!} + \frac{z^5}{5!} + \cdots. \end{align} $$ In the case where $z=0$, the first term on the second line is $0^0/0!$ and $e^0=1. \qquad$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider the following.

Given:
\begin{align}
b_{n} &= \sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{2^{k}}{k+1} \\
S &= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{b_{n-1}}{2^{n} \, n}.
\end{align}
Now:
$$b_{n} = \frac{1}{2} \, \sum_{k=1}^{n+1} \frac{2^{k}}{k} $$
which leads to
\begin{align}
S &= \frac{1}{2} \, \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{2^{k}}{2^{n} \, n \, k} = \frac{1}{2} \, \sum_{n,k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^{n} \, k \, (n+k)}  = \frac{\pi^{2}}{8}.
\end{align}

An alternate view is:
\begin{align}
b_{n} &= \sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{2^{k}}{k+1} = \sum_{k=0}^{n} 2^{k} \, \int_{0}^{1} t^{k-1} \, dt \\
&= \int_{0}^{1} \left( \sum_{k=0}^{n} (2 t)^{k} \right) \, dt \\
&= \int_{0}^{1} \frac{1 - (2 t)^{n+1}}{1-2 t} \, dt.
\end{align}
Now,
\begin{align}
S &= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^{n} \, n} \, \int_{0}^{1} \frac{1 - (2 t)^{n}}{1-2 t} \, dt \\
&= \int_{0}^{1} \frac{\ln(2) + \ln(1-t)}{1-2 t} \, dt \\
&= \left[ \frac{1}{2} \, Li_{2}(2 t -1) \right]_{0}^{1} = \frac{1}{2} \, (Li_{2}(1) - Li_{2}(-1) ) \\
&= \frac{1}{2} \, \left(\frac{\pi^2}{6} + \frac{\pi^2}{12} \right) = \frac{\pi^{2}}{8}. 
\end{align}
Note: $Li_{2}(x)$ is the dilogarithm function.

Comment: While your value is consistent with what OP calculated, I am still puzzled. $b_n \gg H_n$, yet $\displaystyle \frac{3}{2} \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{H_n}{n2^n} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{b_n}{n2^n}$. I would expect a much bigger difference.

Comment: how do you come from $\frac{1}{2} \, \sum_{n,k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^{n} \, k \, (n+k)}$ to $\frac{\pi^2}{8}$? This does not seem very straightforward to me...

Answer (score 2):

This sum is the [Euler transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_transform#Euler_transform) of the series $$1-0+\frac1{3^2}-0+\frac1{5^2}-0+\frac1{7^2}-\ldots = \frac{\pi^2}{6}-\frac{\pi^2}{24}=\frac{\pi^2}{8}.$$